# Structure-preserving matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For a given matrix $A$, consider  the set of all real matrices $\mathcal{A}$ whose entries have the same positions as nonzero elements of $A$. For example,  if 
$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 5\end{bmatrix},\quad \text{then}\quad \mathcal{A}=\Big\{ \begin{bmatrix} a& b \\ 0 & c \end{bmatrix}, (a,b,c)\in\mathbb{R}^{3}\Big\}.$$

By "structure-preserving matrices", I mean matrices $J$ such that **for a given $A$**, $JA\in\mathcal{A}$. I am wondering if it possible to characterize $J$ nicely.

For example, 
$$\text{if } A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \text{ or }  A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \text{ then $J$ is of the form }\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & c\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\text{if } A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \text{ or }  A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, \text{ then $J$ is of the form }\begin{bmatrix} a & 0 \\ b & c\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\text{if } A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}, \text{ then $J$ is of the form }\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix} \text{ (no restriction on $J$)}.$$

So it is tedious but possible to characterise $J$ for $2\times 2$ matrices:

- if $A$ has no zero elements, there are no restriction on $J$.
- if $A$ has one zero element of row 1 (or 2), $J_{12}=0$ (or $J_{21}=0$).
- if $A$ has two zero elements and they are in the same column, there are no restriction on $J$.
- if $A$ has two zero elements and they are in the same row 1 (or 2), $J_{21}=0$ (or $J_{12}=0$).
- if $A$ is diagonal or anti-diagonal, $J$ is diagonal.
- if $A$ has exactly one non-zero element on row 1 (or 2), $J_{21}=0$ (or $J_{12}=0$)
- if $A$ is zero, there are no no restrictions on $J$.

Are there known results about such matrices $J$, and is there a nice way of summarizing this in higher dimensions?

Comment: can we not proceed to $3 \times 3$ matrices, then to $4 \times 4$ matrices, and so on and so forth, using your technique on the $2 \times 2$ matrices? After $4 \times 4$, we might be able to come up with at least some conjectures for $n \times n$.

Comment: You might wanna consider revising your post; if $A$ has no zero elements, then can we take $J$ to be the zero matrix, for example?

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud No because $JA$ would be zero which is not in $\mathcal{A}$ ($0$ does not have the same "structure" as a full matrix).

Comment: but you've stated that if $A$ has no zero elements, then there are no restrictions on $J$, but this evidently is not true because $J$ cannot be the zero matrix. Right?

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud Oh I see, you are right. I'll relax the condition from "having the same structure" to have "nonzero elements of $JA$" must correspond to "nonzero elements of $A$".

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud I just saw the edit of your first comment. Yes, maybe, but it's very tedious!! Even for $3\times 3$ matrices there are dozens of possibilities... I was hoping this was a known problem or someone would have a good approach to tackle it.

Comment: Do you mean that $\mathcal A = \{ \cdots \mid (a,b,c) \in (\mathbb R \setminus \{0\})^3 \}$ in your example, by any chance?

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Actually I just changed from $\mathbb{R}^{*3}$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ following Saaqib Mahmuud's comments. This avoids considering all the combinaisons of elements of $A$ which would be zero, so it's much simpler now. The structure-preserving is to be understood as an inclusion, and with this terminology, $\mathbf{0}$ preserves all structures: it does not change zero entries of $A$ to nonzero.

Comment: What if $A=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ and $J=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\1&-1&1\end{bmatrix}$? Then $JA$ preserves the zero in the last entry for this particular $A$, but not for a different $A$ with the same nonzero structure. To avoid this, you would want the condition that $JA'\in\mathcal A$ for any $A'\in\mathcal A$.

Comment: @anderstood : I wanted to write an answer but I didn't because I wasn't sure what you meant. You should look up "Schur decomposition". In the coordinate free case, the notion of "stabilizing a complete flag" seems to be related to what you are looking for in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

In this context it is better to consider $A$ not as a matrix but as a collection of column vectors, because the $j$th column of $JA$ is nothing but $J$ times the $j$th column of $A$. So we want to find the set of matrices $J$ which preserve the zero entries of a given collection of column vectors. This readily gives the conditions on $J$.

For clarity, we will consider a specific $3$-dimensional example. Consider the vector $a = (x,y,z)$, with $y=0$ and $x,z\ne 0$, that is, $a$ lies in the $xz$-plane and has no component along $y$. Then we require $Ja$ to also lie in the $xz$-plane, so $(Ja)_2 = J_{21}x + J_{23}z=0$. If $x$ and $z$ can be arbitrary (see my comment on the question), then we need $J_{21}=0$ and $J_{23}=0$.

This can be generalized easily: if any column of $A$ has a zero $i$th entry and a nonzero $j$th entry, then $J_{ij}=0$. Now take the conjunction of the conditions arising from all such zero-nonzero same-column pairs.